# ODBC with jBASE

Tags: database, nosql, odbc

I want to use jBASE as database on my new web-application. But it seems that I have to use jBASE BASIC (jBC) to interact with the database. I know what jEDI does, but I don't know how to use it. Does any one know, how I can perform CRUD on jBASE from a php page using some ODBC or jEDI? I'm newbie on jBASE, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why nosql or jbase get enough attention. Not a single comment even though I put bounty. :'( I would put 500 bounty bt I don't have ..

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like anything out there in terms of samples, so you'd have to figure out one on your own after downloading the drivers.

If you have the luxury of picking your technologies, I recommend not using this particular combo.  Even if you do figure out how to get things working -- you're going to run into snags and there isn't going to be much out there in the ways of helping you.

I'd recommend picking a server language that has good documentation/examples with that DB, or pick another DB and migrate over.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Vultar's jBase ODBC driver](http://www.vultar.md/products/odbc-driver-for-jbase).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 5 1/2 years late, but jBASE does now support RESTful Services, along with ODBC, jDBC, Java and .NET through jAgent.  It will require some knowledge of BASIC, but there is documentation on the docs.jbase.com site and support is quick to answer questions.

https://docs.jbase.com/30312-jagent/introduction-to-jagent